# Grunt criando arquivos errados

Tags: node.js, grunt

Estou usando o `grunt-hogan`, no `Gruntfile` está essas definições.

```js
"use strict";

module.exports = function(grunt) {

var config;

config = {
    hogan: {
        tmp: 'template.html',
        output: 'js/tmp/mytemplate.js'
    },
    clean: {
      all: ['js/tmp', 'dest', 'src']
    }
};

grunt.initConfig(config);

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-hogan');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean', 'hogan']);

};
```

**Ele está criando dois arquivos, "src" e "dest".**
O arquivo **src** fica internamente como eu quero, porém não com a extensão `js` e nome e local que eu defino, quero compilar o `template.html` para `mytemplate.js`, como ficou claro no código.

Reparei também que o `src` vem com informações desnecessárias.

To usando o `grunt-hogan` para ficar mais ágil o desenvolvimento, pois com o hogan apenas eu teria que a casa atualização mandar gerar o arquivo na mão.